# Code returning node instead of value of subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am very new to programming and am having a problem with some code for a class I am taking. I need to make a bank account class that returns the balance, adds a deposit, makes a withdrawal, and prints a statement with the current interest rate. I am stuck trying to get the the main class to return the values of the savings account class. Instead it returns the node value and I can't figure out what I a doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Code is below.
FinalExam.java

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class FinalExam
{
    SavingsAccount savings;
    static String name;
    static double balance;    

    public static void main (String[] args) throws NegativeAmountException, InsufficientFundsException {
    double amount = 0;
    SavingsAccount savings = null;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   try
   {
       savings = new SavingsAccount("Penny Saved", 500.00, .05);
       System.out.println(savings);
   }
   catch(NegativeAmountException e)
   {
      System.out.println("NegativeAmountException: " + e.getMessage());
      System.exit(1);

   }

   System.out.println(savings);
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter your deposit amount: ");
   amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
   System.out.println(savings);
   System.out.println("Enter your withdrawal amount:  ");
   amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
   savings.postInterest();
   System.out.println(savings);
}
}
```

BankAccount.java

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner; //Import for scanner


public class BankAccount {
  public String name;
  public double balance;     

  //set name and balance 
  // make sure balance is not negative
  // throw exception if balance is negative

  public BankAccount(String name, double balance)throws NegativeAmountException {
      if (balance < 0)
        throw new NegativeAmountException("Cannot create a BankAccount with a negative balance");


  }

    public BankAccount(String name)
            throws NegativeAmountException 
  {
    // set name and use 0 balance 
        name = null;
        balance = 0;
  }


  public void deposit(double amount) throws NegativeAmountException {
      if (amount < 0)
        throw new NegativeAmountException("Cannot deposit a negative amount: " + amount);
      balance = balance + amount;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) throws InsufficientFundsException, NegativeAmountException {
    if (amount > balance)
        throw new InsufficientFundsException("Cannot withdraw more than the current balance of this BankAccount");
    if (amount < 0)
        throw new NegativeAmountException("Cannot withdraw a negative amount: " + amount);
    balance = balance - amount;
  }

  public double getBalance() {

    return balance;

  }
  // print bank statement including customer name
 // and current account balance

  public void printStatement() {
      System.out.println("BankAccount owned by: " + name +  "    balance: $" + balance);
    }
}
```

SavingsAcount.java

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
{
    double interest;

    public SavingsAccount(String name, double balance, double interest) throws NegativeAmountException {

      super(name, balance);


    }
    public double getInterest()
    {
    return interest;
    }
    public void postInterest() {

       balance = balance + ((balance * interest)/12);
    }

    public void printStatement() {
        super.printStatement();
      System.out.println("Account for " + name +  " Saved" + balance + "    balance: $" + "Current Interest Rate is" + interest);
      }
 }
```

I know the last part of the FinalExam.java is incomplete, but I am trying to get the statement to print out before I move on the other issues. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I addition to the other answers, you did not set the interest field in the SavingsAccount constructor. After `super(name, balance);`, add `this.interest = interest;`

Comment: The same goes for the BankAccount constructor; the fields were not set.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan Don't use tags in comments. For code, put it between ``. It looks `like this`.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan You were right on. That solved my last issue. I think I am good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am stuck trying to get the the main class to return the values of the savings account class. Instead it returns the node value and I can't figure out what I a doing wrong.

Your problem is that you are calling

```
savings = new SavingsAccount("Penny Saved", 500.00, .05);
System.out.println(savings);
```

`println` automatically calls the `toString` method on its argument. Since you didn't `@Override` the `toString` method of `SavingsAccount`, it prints what you call the "node value".

Your `SavingsAccount` has a method

```
public void printStatement()
```

which seems to print the information you want. So call it instead of `println`.

Comment: That was it, I knew I was missing something simple. I think the last issue I could use help with is that now that I am calling the correct method, it is only returning the interest rate but not the account name and balance. Instead, it is returning BankAccount owned by: null    balance: $0.0Current Interest Rate0.05. Any suggestions?

Comment: I actually got this handled from the other comments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Probowlactic Look at the constructors you are calling. You call `SavingsAccount(String, double, double)` which does nothing excepet call the superconstructor `BankAccount(String, double`, which does nothing. You need to call the methods in those classes too, not just the constructors.

Answer (score 1):

When you print an object using `System.out.println(savings)` method, it internally calls the `toString()` method on that object. You need to implement the `toString()` method for both the classes `SavingsAccount` and `BankAccount`.

For the `SavingsAccount` use this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "SavingsAccount{" +
      super.toString() +
      ", interest=" + interest +
      '}';
}
```

For `BankAccount` use this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "BankAccount{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      ", balance=" + balance +
      '}';
}
```

---

Currently you are not setting the instance variables in the class. You are checking for negative balance and throwing the exception. 
Also you need to improve the constructor in `BankAccount` class as follow:

```
public BankAccount(String name, double balance)throws NegativeAmountException {
  if (balance < 0) {
    throw new NegativeAmountException("Cannot create a BankAccount with a negative balance");
  }
  this.name = name;
  this.balance = balance;
}
// Update the SavingsAccount class constructor as well
public SavingsAccount(String name, double balance, double interest) throws NegativeAmountException {
  super(name, balance);
  this.interest = interest;  // this is missing in your code.
}
```

---

Other thing which I have observed it that, you are creating multiple instances of Scanner class. You can use the same `keyboard` instance every where in the main method. No need to create multiple instances. One of them is unnecessary.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the FinalExam.java class you suppose to print the values of the SavingsAccount.java class but you are getting the address. This id because in FinalExam.java class `System.out.println(savings);` rather than that yous should use like `savings.printStatement();`. May be I am not wrong what I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already given, but there is also problem in your BankAccount class constructors, you did not assign instance variable to constructor arguments, you just check constraint so,

```
public BankAccount(String name, double balance)throws NegativeAmountException {
      if (balance < 0)
        throw new NegativeAmountException("Cannot create a BankAccount with a negative balance");
      this.name = name;
      this.balance = balance;
}
```

and

```
public BankAccount(String name) {
    // set name and use 0 balance 
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = 0;   
}
```

thanks:)